# Converting Coverage files into shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, esri-coverage-format

I am attempting to convert coverage files into shapefiles using arcpy.  This is not the e00 files, but the bin files.   ArcGIS help suggests that it can be done using **[FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000)**, but I am getting an error saying "parcels does not exist or not supported".

```
fileName = 'C:\\May_2014_Parcels' + "\\" + filename + "\\" + subfilename + "\\parcels"
                   arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fileName,  

r'C:\May_2014_Parcels\Output\parcels.gdb', filename + "_" + subfilename)
```

How do I actually get the featureclass out of the coverage file so I can perform this task?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you might find it easier to use `os.path.join()` instead of concatenating double backslashes and folder names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coverages are like TAB and CAD files in that they can have multiple feature types. For example, a polygon coverage has polygons, lines, nodes, points (labels) and optionally tics.

```
'C:\\May_2014_Parcels' + "\\" + filename + "\\" + subfilename + "\\parcels\\polygon"
```

should do the trick for accessing the polygon records, likewise if you want just the lines then:

```
'C:\\May_2014_Parcels' + "\\" + filename + "\\" + subfilename + "\\parcels\\arc"
```

would do it. Note arc feature type is a polyline, not actually an *arc*!

**note** do not copy coverages with windows explorer unless you are copying the whole workspace, doing so will render them *utterly useless*. If you cannot 'see' inside the coverages in ArcCatalog like this:

[image: Inside a coverage]

then it is already broken!

Comment: +1 I was thinking that the Coverage tools (and an Advanced license) were needed to convert coverage format data.

Comment: It mostly worked, and I am using just the basic ArcView license.

Comment: It used to be that way, but now that coverages are going the way of the Dodo reading a coverage is fine in Basic (ArcView). Creating a coverage still takes an Advanced (INFO) license I think.

Comment: That's true.   All I am doing is converting about 1800 coverage files that a local county government has been using for quite some time.